# how to select a record from a html table in a mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

i have a html table that is used for selection, like a fancy select tag

Via jquery i get the selected row:

```
$('#meTable tbody tr ').on('click', function(event) {
    doStuff();
});
```

if the page is viewed in a mobile device instead of a laptop or pc, how could i achieve the same behavior? is it safe to do it via onkeydown ?

thanks

Comment: This code should already work on mobile, as `click` is triggered on a mobile tap. Can you confirm that it's not working as expected?

Comment: @JonUleis thanks jon, i am new to mobile development and had no idea about that. right now i cannot access the code to test it, please post this as an answer and as i soon as i can test i'll be happy to select it as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

This code should already work on mobile, as `click` is triggered on a mobile tap.

(Per your request, posting this as an answer.)